# Link Not Working in CSS 3 animation

Tags: html, css

I have implemented a **CSS3 Animation** for a Div-Element which has Header text and "Read more"-link. I'm using `translateX` function to animate the container from left to right of the screen.

The problem is that the "Read more"-link which has an anchor goes to unclickable while the box animation. But when the animation ends the anchor becomes clickable.

Can anyone help me finding the problem behind this?

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h3>Title1</h3>
  <p class="sub-text">Title1 Desc </p>
  <p class="read-more"><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 27%;
  width: 62%;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
div h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 30px 0px 5px 0px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
div p.sub-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  margin: 0px;
}

div p.read-more {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 10px 25px 20px; 
}
div p.read-more a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(223, 75, 20);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

titleAnimation { 
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300%);
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(10%);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5%);
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-10%);
  }
  25% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Working Sample is
http://jsfiddle.net/a4enq/

Comment: Just giving the code and not the CSS isn't going to work if you need help. We need to know at least the browser(s) it's occurring in, and a working code sample on JSfiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Ya, provide a jsfiddle which replicate your issue please

Comment: Yes, obviously, during a transition in CSS, the elements are read only and they cannot be clickable. You cannot do anything about this.

Comment: seems to be a chrome issue.. it works fine with Firefox.. (*btw you are missing the `@keyframes`* part on your sample code..

Comment: I've just added the animation code for chrome only for sample

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to try and click the link whilst its moving?

Anyway, I believe that this is the default browser behavior (Chrome) because when you are using translate(X,Y,Z,3d) it creates a new layer of the elements moving and repaints the element you're moving and make everything position: relative and disables all anchors until the animation has stopped.

Comment: I'm not going to click anchor while animating. When the animation slows at the end i may need to click readmore. So what is the alternative solution?

Comment: The alternative is to use jQuery and position absolute from left to right as this wont create a layer like CSS3 animation would.

Answer (score 0):

You could use margins or left position for the animation (*so at to manipulate the DOM and not the renderer*)

This way it will work but it will lose hardware accelerated benefits

http://jsfiddle.net/L5tv8/1/

```
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left:300%;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:10%;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left:5%;
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left:-10%;
  }
  25% { opacity: 1 }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```